# How to enable global menu bar for Emacs on Ubuntu (Unity 11.04)

Tags: emacs, ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04

I use latest Ubuntu 11.04 which has Unity desktop. I am learning to use Emacs 23.

As you know, Unity has top panel. I want to enable global menu bar for Emacs so that I could save valuable screen space. (I use small screen laptop)

How to enable global menu bar? Your help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

appmenu-gtk (which provides the global menu bar) specifically [blacklisted emacs](https://code.launchpad.net/~mterry/appmenu-gtk/blacklist-emacs/+merge/57934) since it does not [play nicely together](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libdbusmenu/+bug/673302) so unfortunately you probably can't use it with emacs.

Comment: @ alexmurray 'unfortunately you probably can't use it with emacs' what do you mean? Didn't get you.

Comment: As I said, the developers have specifically blacklisted emacs from being able to show its menu in the global menu bar - so you won't be able to get emacs to use the global menu bar.

Answer (score 8):

1. Use your favorite editor to open this file: `/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so`
2. Find the word "emacs"
3. Change "emacs" to other word
4. Save the file
5. `sudo ldconfig`

update:The file of "libappmenu.so" moved to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies" now in ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I'm out of words. This is the most hackish answer I've ever read. Please, do not attempt this fix *unless you understand the consequences of manually editing a binary executable*! Otherwise it is very easy to corrupt the said file, which might cause all kind of damage to your system!

Answer (score 2):

Cleaner way to circument the blacklist:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/emacs somewhere_on_PATH/emacs-with-global-menu
```

any name except "emacs" works.

You might need workaround for updating menus from http://code.google.com/p/gnome2-globalmenu/issues/detail?id=357#c8 (don't know if still relevant, or if that's the only problem):

```
(defun menuupdate () (menu-bar-mode -1) (menu-bar-mode 1)) 
(add-hook 'window-configuration-change-hook 'menuupdate)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in Emacs 24, `window-configuration-change-hook` seems to be called in turn by `menu-bar-mode`, so you have an infinite recursion. The following seems to work for me though:
`(add-hook 'menu-bar-update-hook
          (lambda ()
            (interactive)
            (progn (menu-bar-mode -1)
                   (menu-bar-mode 1))))`

Comment: @P-Nuts emacs gets really laggy with those, unfortunately, specially using evil mode